# Circular UIView scale animation goes back to square sometimes

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I put a UIView on center of the screen with Autolayout. This UIView is a square sized to be 15% of screen width. Then on my controller I add the cornerRadius :

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.frame.size.width / 2.0
}
```

Then when user click on a button, the circular view is scaling down with a first animation.

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.1, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
    self.circle.alpha = 0.0
    self.circle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01)
}) { (finished) -> Void in
    scaleUp()
}

private func scaleUp() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.circle.alpha = 1.0
        self.circle.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
    }) { (finished) -> Void in

    }
}
```

Sometimes the scale down animation doesn't work properly. Before starting the cornerRadius is removed and my UIView become a square. But sometimes my animation works well and the circle scale down animation is OK.

Moreover the scale up animation seems to work well all the time.

I don't understand why the scale down animation isn't working all the time.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When animating with *Auto Layout* enabled, it is usually a good idea to call `layoutIfNeeded` on your view before starting the animation and again in the loop.

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.frame.size.width / 2.0
}

@IBAction func scaleDownUp(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.circle.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0.1, options: .CurveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.circle.alpha = 0.0
        self.circle.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.01, 0.01)
        self.circle.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (finished) -> Void in
        self.scaleUp()
    }
}

private func scaleUp() {
    self.circle.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0.0, options: .CurveEaseInOut, animations: {
        self.circle.alpha = 1.0
        self.circle.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        self.circle.layoutIfNeeded()
    }) { (finished) -> Void in

    }
}
```

Comment: I still have the same behavior with call to layoutIfNeeded()

Comment: Hmmm.  What if you call `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` instead?  I'm not able to reproduce your problem.  I have a centered view that is 15% of screen width.  Height is equal to width.  Is there anything else I could do to see this?

Comment: It seems to fix the problem partially because now I sometimes have a square view during the scaleUp animation. I will try with a new project to see If I can reproduce the bug.

Comment: I'm using XCode 7.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Try using bounds instead of frame in this method:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    circle.layer.cornerRadius = circle.frame.size.width / 2.0
}
```

It worked for me =)